# Finding the rank of matrices with its image

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

how can I find the rank of matrix $A$ when I have it's image?Imagine that A is invertible matrix. What I mean is that for every $y$ there is an $x$ such that $Ax=y$

Comment: If $A$ is invertible, it must be square and have full rank (i.e. the rank = the number of rows = the number of columns). If by invertible, you mean that it is **right** invertible (that is onto or surjective), then the rank will just be the number or rows in the matrix.

Comment: but I think that the rank of a matrices should be the number of the distinct rows or columns.

Comment: No. The rank of a matrix is the number of **linearly independent** rows (or columns). Certainly they must be distinct, but this is not enough.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean that $A{\bf x} = {\bf y}$ has a solution for all ${\bf y}$, then $A$ must be full rank -- that is the rank of $A$ must be the same as the number of rows of $A$.

Why? If not, in the RREF one has a row of zeros. Append the column $[0\;0\;\cdots\;0\;1]^T$, reverse row reduction and you'll get a ${\bf y}$ which makes $A{\bf x}={\bf y}$ inconsistent.

In general, the set of all images: $\{ {\bf y} \;|\; \mbox{there exists } {\bf x} \mbox{ such that } A{\bf x} = {\bf y} \}$ is called the **column space** of $A$. The rank of the matrix is the dimension of this vector space. In fact, rank = the dimension of the column space = the number of pivot columns = the number of linearly independent columns = the dimension of the row space = the number of non-zero rows in the RREF = the number of linearly independent rows.